# Cannot delete file because it is in use

Tags: java, file, stream, delete-file

I will post the code first, then elaborate:

```
public void createPackage(String uploadedZipLocation) throws BadException, IOException, SAXException {
    String extractedFolderPath = uploadedZipLocation.split("\\.zip")[0];
    File tempFolder = null;
    Source xml = null;
    try {
        xml = new StreamSource(extractedFolderPath + "/web.xml");
        validatePkgXml(xml, extractedFolderPath + "/web.xml");
        xml = null; 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (BadException bpe) {
        xml = null;
        tempFolder = new File(extractedFolderPath);
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(tempFolder); // **** Can't delete the folder because it is in use.  web.xml is still being read in validatePkgXml I think
        throw bpe;
    }
}


private void validatePkgXml(Source xmlStream, String xmlPath) throws BadException, IOException, SAXException{
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File("/C:/workspacesFresh2/web.xsd"));
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.setErrorHandler(new PackageXMLValidationErrorHandler());
    try {
      validator.validate(xmlStream);
      logger.info(xmlStream.getSystemId() + " is valid");
    } catch (SAXException e) {
      logger.error(xmlStream.getSystemId() + " is NOT valid");
      throw new BadException(xmlPath, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

I am trying to get an xml file and validate it against an `xsd` schema.  If the validation fails, I want to delete the folder containing the xml file.  When the validation fails, I cannot delete the folder because `web.xml` is still in use.  I've tried setting the `Source` to `null` after it fails validation, but the `web.xml` is somehow still in use.  Any ideas how to unlock the file so I can delete it?  Side note: If the validation is successful, then the deleting the folder is also successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the InputStream before deleting the folder.

I have not tested this code, but it should give you the idea:

```
public void createPackage(String uploadedZipLocation) throws BadException, IOException, SAXException {
    String extractedFolderPath = uploadedZipLocation.split("\\.zip")[0];
    File tempFolder = null;
    StreamSource xml = null;
    FileInputStream file = null;

    try {
        file = new FileInputStream(extractedFolderPath + "/web.xml");
        xml = new StreamSource(file);
        validatePkgXml(xml, extractedFolderPath + "/web.xml");
        xml.getInputStream().close(); 
        //xml = null; 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        xml.getInputStream().close(); 
        throw e;
    } catch (BadException bpe) {
        //xml = null;
        xml.getInputStream().close(); 
        tempFolder = new File(extractedFolderPath);
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(tempFolder); // **** Can't delete the folder because it is in use.  web.xml is still being read in validatePkgXml I think
        throw bpe;
    }
}
```

Hope it works! Good Luck!

[edit]
btw. you should ALWAYS close Files and Stream to avoid memory leaks, resulting OutOfMemoryExceptions and ConcurrentModificationExceptions.
[/edit]

Comment: I can't find the `getInputStream()` method.

Comment: I needed to use `StreamSource` instead of just `Source` to get that method.

Comment: ^^ true, I corrected it in the sample code. Is is working now?

Comment: Not yet, when I call `getInputStream()`, I receive a `null pointer exception`.

Comment: The `inputStream` attribute of `xml` is null when it is created.

Comment: arrr! That is indeed possible, we have no Input Stream. I incoporated Pats answer into mine. Now we have made an InputStream from the file, so we should get an InputStream to close. True?

Comment: Likely that we could possibly close the FileInputStream directly now, instead of using the getINputStream Method on StreamSource.

Comment: Yes, I just saw that edit.  That is very important it seems.  Thanks for your help.  It works perfectly now!

Answer (score 2):

try

```
public void createPackage(String uploadedZipLocation) throws BadException, IOException, SAXException {
    String extractedFolderPath = uploadedZipLocation.split("\\.zip")[0];
    File tempFolder = null;
    FileInputStream file = null;
    Source xml = null;
    try {
        file = new FileInputStream(extractedFolderPath + "/web.xml");
        xml = new StreamSource(file);
        validatePkgXml(xml, extractedFolderPath + "/web.xml");
        xml = null; 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (BadException bpe) {
        file.close();
        tempFolder = new File(extractedFolderPath);
        FileUtils.deleteDirectory(tempFolder);
        throw bpe;
    }
}
```

Comment: The use of `File` as the argument to `new StreamSource(File ...)` helped in fixing my issue!   Thanks